# Hibernate deleting parent objects when trying to delete child

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate

I am having self join table CATEGORY. When I am trying to delete child entries, my parent entries ae also getting deleted. I am using Oracle 19.3 Db.

Eg.

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "parent",
        "display_name": "parent",
        "parent_id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "child",
        "display_name": "child",
        "parent_id": 5
    }
]
```

Upon deleting entry with 6, entry of id 5 is also getting deleted.
My Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CATEGORY")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, updatable = true, unique = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "display_name", nullable = false, updatable = true, unique = false)
    private String displayName;

    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Category parent;

    //Setter and Getters and Constructors
```

Logs from Spring boot are as follow

```
2021-04-30 14:50:57.345 DEBUG 2588 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    delete 
    from
        category 
    where
        id=?
2021-04-30 14:50:57.345 TRACE 2588 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [4]
2021-04-30 14:50:57.403 DEBUG 2588 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    delete 
    from
        category 
    where
        id=?
2021-04-30 14:50:57.405 TRACE 2588 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [3]
2021-04-30 14:50:57.518  INFO 2588 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.c.service.impl.CategoryServiceImpl   : Course category deleted with chain
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to look into your @Cascade annotation with hibernate. It cascades operation between related entities and it looks you are cascading all actions.
cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, which all includes CascadeType.REMOVE.
Refer: https://www.educba.com/cascade-in-hibernate/